# Force jQuery to call a query every X hour?

Tags: jquery

I've had some troubles with events on my PHPMyAdmin due to I lack super user permission, I contacted my host and they don't seem to want to help me. So now I got the idea of running a certain php query every hour and I wonder if it's possible?

This is the query I want to run:

```
UPDATE users SET field = '0'
```

At first I thought of using the `load()` function within jQuery, so after you've loaded the page it would run the query after an hour, but even then I'm not certainly sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to do this inside PHP itself rather than having a clientside environment do it.
Store the last time you ran the procedure, and when a page is called, check if the difference between that time and the current time is greater than x. if so, run the procedure. or even better, run it as a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

To use JavaScript/jQuery for this purpose you will have to have your window open for the whole time as it is a client-side language (for running JavaScript server-side take a look at NodeJS). But if that is okay for you, you may use `$(document).ready()` along with `setInterval(function() {//YOUR AJAX REQUEST HERE//}, interval)`.

But also you could attach a PHP function (that check's when was the last UPDATE run, and run it if it was long ago) to certain requests. But don't use it on every page load, especially if your website has high amount of visitors to avoid causing unneeded requests to the database.